# Do transformers generate ELF waves?

Tags: rf, transformer, elf

Do AC transformers (particularly the 60 hertz ones) generate an [Extremely Low Frequency (ELF) wave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extremely_low_frequency) at 60 hertz or is it just a plain oscillating magnetic field with no electronic part 90º out of phase like normal RF waves.

Comment: Elf Wave:  http://candieanderson.com/images/2012/12/santa-claus-and-his-elf-wave--565x484.png

Answer (score 1):

1) Are transformers generators? NO.

2) Do transformers radiate E/M waves? Generally, transformers are very poor at radiating E/M waves.

3) Do transforms have an E/M near field? Typically transformers have a very small near-field considering the amount of power they transform. All transformers are designed to have a very small near-field because it would be ineffecient: field outside the transformer coils is field that is not being used.

4) Is there a detectible near-field? Yes, if you have the correct equipment.

5) Is there a detectible radiated field? No, not unless you are doing something weird.

6) Is the near-field or the radiated field as detectable as that from a HV transmission line? No, normally not.

Answer (score 0):

The magnetizing current which sets up the magnetic flux on primary winding of a transformer lags input voltage by 90º.